# Jupyter Notebook in VS Code is not working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, miniconda

I'm using Ubuntu, installed Vs Code and anaconda. I've also installed python extension in VS Code, which brings Jupyter Notebook extension. Now, whenever I'm trying to run code from the Jupyter extension, its throwing error as if it requires ipykernel.

Now, my conda 'base' environment has already ipykernel. Why cant Jupyter extension look for ipykernel from the current activated environment?

Is there any explicit settings to be made, to make VS Code Jupyter extension use ipykernel from the current active environment? Please provide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Click here to switch the environment of Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution `python -m ipykernel install --user --name=conda_env_name`